# How do I a wmic path query result which is converted to a "Boolean", into a variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic

From the other Stack Overflow article, I found a very useful piece of code. With my modifications, it returns "true" or "false" if a specific USB device is plugged in.

Is it possible to get this "true" or "false" into a batch variable?

I want to run a batch file who installs a driver automatically if the USB device is plugged in

I already tried the for /F command with a lot of different configurations but

I always get the error:

> 2>&1 was unexpected at this time.

Here is the query that is actually working:

```
wmic path Win32_PnPEntity where "Manufacturer like 'Lenovo' AND Caption like 'Thinkpad USB 3.0 Ethernet Adapter'" get Manufacturer 2>&1 > nul | find /V "" > nul && (echo False) || (echo True)
```

And this is just one variation of for /f comments I tried...

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=2>&1" %%a in ('wmic path Win32_PnPEntity where "Caption like 'Thinkpad USB LAN'" get Caption 2>&1 > nul | find /V "" > nul && (echo False) || (echo True)') do set TEST= %%a
```

Comment: If you want to use `Like`, then where are your wildcards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special characters like `>`, `&`, `)`, etc. must be either escaped or quoted when used within the `IN('cmd')` clause of `FOR /F`.

It is important to know that the IN clause command is executed via `CMD /C`, which has special quote handling behavior described by the help. In your case, the simplest option is to add enclosing double quotes just inside the single quotes as follows:

```
for /f %%A in ('"wmic path Win32_PnPEntity where "Manufacturer like 'Lenovo' AND Caption like 'Thinkpad USB 3.0 Ethernet Adapter'" get Manufacturer 2>&1 > nul | find /V "" > nul && (echo False) || (echo True)"') do @echo %%A
```

The implicit `CMD /C` will remove the outer most quotes after the `IN()` clause has been safely parsed. Your WHERE clause is also quoted, so in the first parsing pass, it is not quoted. This is OK because your WHERE clause does not have any special characters. If it did, then you would have to do some escaping somewhere.

- Add the extra quotes as I have them, and then escape any special characters in your quoted WHERE clause.
- Or use the original form without the extra quotes and escape any special characters that are not quoted (all characters not in the WHERE clause in your case).

Comment: @Compo - Yes, the use of `LIKE` without wildcards is odd, and possibly suspect. But it is not relevant to the central question.

Comment: This really helps me a lot! Thank you so much for this detailed explanation!